# How do I retrieve the status of my ec2-image using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

In my code, I am trying to create an image from an AMI and then check the state of the new image. However, I am struggling to work out the state of the image. Here is the last thing I have tried:

```
package_name = "RAY"
promotion_id = "101-234"

print "[....] Package Install Complete"
print "[....] Proceeding to Bake AMI"

imagename = package_name + promotion_id
newimageid = conn.create_image(instance_id=bakeryinstanceid, name=imagename, description="Please Work"  )

print "[....] The new Base AMI ID for ", package_name, "is", newimageid

image_status = newimageid.state
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./imagecreate.py", line 58, in <module>
image_status = newimageid.state
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'state'
```

What is the best way to see the status of my new image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `create_image()` returns a string with the image id in it, not an Image object. Using your example, you should do this instead:

```
image_status = get_image(newimageid)
```

`image_status.state` should then hold a string showing your image state, possible values include "pending", "available" and "failed".

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_image
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.create_image